# Unable to register fonts using FontReg.exe in windows 2019 inside dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, fonts, containers

I am unable to run this fontreg.exe on windows 2019 machine inside my dockerfile

I am running using Start-Process .\FontReg.exe

`Start-Process .\FontReg.exe -wait`

It gives no error but font registery does not happen.

`However it works on writing it inside I’m CMD[“powershell.exe”, “Start-Process C:\FontReg.exe”] Or  ENTRYPOINT[powershell.exe”,”Start-Process C:\FontReg.exe]` 
I don’t want to use CMD and entry point

Not sure if this is due to permissions
I have added full access control to the file and even tried to run with containerAdministrator

However this is working perfectly when running it in windows 11 dockerfile

It is strange why this is happening for windows 2019

I have compared the docker version
Both system have same docker version

Please help , I m stuck

I am running using Start-Process .\FontReg.exe

`Start-Process .\FontReg.exe -wait`

Comment: Please share your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're trying to run a PowerShell command in a CMD shell.

Just try:

```
RUN FontReg.exe
```

or switch shells using the `SHELL` instruction:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Start-Process .\FontReg.exe -wait
```